# How to get all order details including payment custmer and shipping details from order id Magento

Tags: magento, get, master-detail, observers

I need to get all order details which includes all payment details, customer details, and shipping details or say all details of a order.
For this I have use a event in my config file

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

and the function in my observer file is

```
public function getorderrealid($observer) {

    print_r($observer->getData());
}
```

the function triggers properly, but it returns the following array

```
Array
(
    [event] => Varien_Event Object
        (
            [_observers:protected] => Varien_Event_Observer_Collection Object
                (
                    [_observers:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [order_ids] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 66
                        )

                    [name] => checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
                )

            [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
            [_origData:protected] => 
            [_idFieldName:protected] => 
            [_isDeleted:protected] => 
            [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [order_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 66
        )

)
```

It gives only order id.

Please suggest how I can get all details of an order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
$orderData = $order->getData();
print_r($orderData);
```

**EDIT**

```
$billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
```

**For credit card information**

CC Last 4 number: `$order->getPayment()->getCcLast4()`

```
$order->getPayment()->getCcExpMonth();
$order->getPayment()->getCcExpYear();
```

when you print `$orderData` you can get following information like

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 45
    [state] => processing
    [status] => pending
    [coupon_code] => stickytest
    [protect_code] => 1036b0
    [shipping_description] => Voucher code discount
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [store_id] => 1
    [customer_id] =>
    [base_discount_amount] => -195.0000
    [base_discount_canceled] =>
    [base_discount_invoiced] =>
    [base_discount_refunded] =>
    [base_grand_total] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_canceled] =>
    [base_shipping_invoiced] =>
    [base_shipping_refunded] =>
    [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_tax_refunded] =>
    [base_subtotal] => 177.2700
    [base_subtotal_canceled] =>
    [base_subtotal_invoiced] =>
    [base_subtotal_refunded] =>
    [base_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_tax_canceled] =>
    [base_tax_invoiced] =>
    [base_tax_refunded] =>
    [base_to_global_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_to_order_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_total_canceled] =>
    [base_total_invoiced] =>
    [base_total_invoiced_cost] =>
    [base_total_offline_refunded] =>
    [base_total_online_refunded] =>
    [base_total_paid] =>
    [base_total_qty_ordered] =>
    [base_total_refunded] =>
    [discount_amount] => -195.0000
    [discount_canceled] =>
    [discount_invoiced] =>
    [discount_refunded] =>
    [grand_total] => 0.0000
    [shipping_amount] => 0.0000
    [shipping_canceled] =>
    [shipping_invoiced] =>
    [shipping_refunded] =>
    [shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [shipping_tax_refunded] =>
    [store_to_base_rate] => 1.0000
    [store_to_order_rate] => 1.0000
    [subtotal] => 177.2700
    [subtotal_canceled] =>
    [subtotal_invoiced] =>
    [subtotal_refunded] =>
    [tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [tax_canceled] =>
    [tax_invoiced] =>
    [tax_refunded] =>
    [total_canceled] =>
    [total_invoiced] =>
    [total_offline_refunded] =>
    [total_online_refunded] =>
    [total_paid] =>
    [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000
    [total_refunded] =>
    [can_ship_partially] =>
    [can_ship_partially_item] =>
    [customer_is_guest] => 1
    [customer_note_notify] => 1
    [billing_address_id] => 89
    [customer_group_id] => 0
    [edit_increment] =>
    [email_sent] => 1
    [forced_shipment_with_invoice] =>
    [gift_message_id] =>
    [payment_auth_expiration] =>
    [paypal_ipn_customer_notified] =>
    [quote_address_id] =>
    [quote_id] => 215
    [shipping_address_id] => 90
    [adjustment_negative] =>
    [adjustment_positive] =>
    [base_adjustment_negative] =>
    [base_adjustment_positive] =>
    [base_shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_subtotal_incl_tax] => 195.0000
    [base_total_due] =>
    [payment_authorization_amount] =>
    [shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000
    [subtotal_incl_tax] => 195.0000
    [total_due] =>
    [weight] => 1.0000
    [customer_dob] =>
    [increment_id] => 100000034
    [applied_rule_ids] => 4
    [base_currency_code] => AUD
    [customer_email] => someone@somewhere.com
    [customer_firstname] => billing[firstname]
    [customer_lastname] => billing[lastname]
    [customer_middlename] =>
    [customer_prefix] =>
    [customer_suffix] =>
    [customer_taxvat] =>
    [discount_description] => stickytest
    [ext_customer_id] =>
    [ext_order_id] =>
    [global_currency_code] => AUD
    [hold_before_state] =>
    [hold_before_status] =>
    [order_currency_code] => AUD
    [original_increment_id] =>
    [relation_child_id] =>
    [relation_child_real_id] =>
    [relation_parent_id] =>
    [relation_parent_real_id] =>
    [remote_ip] => 192.168.0.18
    [shipping_method] => matrixrate_matrixrate_free
    [store_currency_code] => AUD
    [store_name] => Main Website
Main Store
English
    [x_forwarded_for] =>
    [customer_note] =>
    [created_at] => 2012-11-19 10:53:11
    [updated_at] => 2012-11-19 10:53:12
    [total_item_count] => 1
    [customer_gender] =>
    [base_custbalance_amount] =>
    [currency_base_id] =>
    [currency_code] =>
    [currency_rate] =>
    [custbalance_amount] =>
    [is_hold] =>
    [is_multi_payment] =>
    [real_order_id] =>
    [tax_percent] =>
    [tracking_numbers] =>
    [hidden_tax_amount] => 17.7300
    [base_hidden_tax_amount] => 17.7300
    [shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt] => 0.0000
    [hidden_tax_invoiced] =>
    [base_hidden_tax_invoiced] =>
    [hidden_tax_refunded] =>
    [base_hidden_tax_refunded] =>
    [shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000
    [onestepcheckout_customercomment] => onestepcheckout_comments
    [onestepcheckout_customerfeedback] => Google
    [payment_authorization_expiration] =>
    [forced_do_shipment_with_invoice] =>
    [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
)
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: HI it prints the data as above you show , but can you please tell me how can i get all shipping address and billing address and payment details including credit card details .

Comment: that works great , can you please tell me can i get full cc number not only last 4

Comment: @RohitGoel magento save only last 4 digit credit card number. I think you don't get full credit card number.

Comment: i use this code to print order details but it`s show no thing on output, no result and no error $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
$orderData = $order->getData();
print_r($orderData);

Comment: @mahdi $orderid exists in your database ?

Comment: @KeyurShah Can you please tell me how to get contact or mobile number? For both registered & guest users?